# Circular clipper in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, clip, circle

In QGIS 3.14 I wish to clip a layer to the features within a circular area.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a new polygon layer and add a circle feature to that new layer, then use the existing clip function.

```
Layer_>Create Layer->Temporary Scratch Layer. 
Edit->Add Circle->(pick your circle method)
Draw the circle
Toggle editing
Highlight the layer you wish to clip in the layers pane
Vector->GeoProcessing Tools->Clip
Select your temporary layer as the clipping layer.
```

I've been having problems with circles in non-projected layers (the circle looks like two overlapping circles), so check that your temporary layer and the layer you want to clip are in a projected CRS if you are getting weird results.

Comment: In the main menu bar select Edit->Add Circle

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve exactly what I wanted thus:  Created point layer with a projected CRS (appears to be important to get an accurate circle), and add a point feature where the centre of the proposed circle will be.  Select the point and then Vector/Geoprocessing Tools/Buffer.  Input layer is the point layer.  Set distance to the radius of the proposed circle.  Set Segments to say 25 to get an accurate circle plot.  Select 'Create Temporary Layer' and Run.  You can now use the created temporary layer to clip any input layer via Vector/Geoprocessing Tools/Clip.